# How to bind render targets?

Tags: c#, directx-11, sharpdx

I don't understand how can I bind the callback of render target?

In `c++` I would set it with references to the interface device by calling `_somedevice->OMSetRenderTargets(...)`.
How can I do this with `SharpDX`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_device.OutputMerger.SetRenderTargets` as far as I remember. I'm on my mobile now so I can't really elaborate, but the OM methods are all in the OutputMerger instance.